# htmlフォームのpostからのレスポンスを取得し、その値をサーバーに自動送信したいです。

Tags: javascript, php, html, ajax

大変お世話になっております。

以下の様な設定で、`http://www.test.com/test.html` というページのhtmlのフォームからユーザーIDとパスワードを入力し、送信ボタンをクリックし、`https://server.com/send1` へPOST送信すると、一番下に表示されている様に、urlに`https://server.com/send1`と表示されたまま、画面に正しいresponceが表示されます。

javascriptを使用して、responceを取得次第、`https://server.com/send2`に、この返ってきたresponceを付加して自動的に送信しなければならなく、以下の様な設定にしておりますが、`https://server.com/send2` にリダイレクトされません。

それは、以下のjavascriptの記述に問題があるのか、あるいは画面に表示されているresponseが`http://www.test.com/test.html`に実際には返ってきていないため（urlは`https://server.com/send1`の状態である為）、よってそのページ内にあるjavascriptに読まれていないためなのかなどが分かりません。

どのような記述、設定にすれば上記の目的を達成できるか、ご教授頂けませんでしょうか。

```
http://www.test.com/test.html

<script language="JavaScript"><!--

xhr.onreadystatechange = function() {

    if(xhr.readyState === 4 && xhr.status === 200) {

        $responce = window.sessionStorage.getItem('responce');

        var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest(); 
        xhr.open('POST',  'https://server.com/send2');
        xhr.setRequestHeader('content-type',  'application/x-www-form-urlencoded');
        xhr.send('responce=$responce');

    }
}

</script>

<form action="https://server.com/send1" method="post">
<input name="USER" id="USER"  type="hidden" value=""/>
<input name="PWD" id="PWD" type="hidden" value="" />
<input type="submit" value="送信">
</form>
```

以上のフォームの送信ボタンをクリックすると以下が表示される。（responceは正しい内容）

```
url: https://server.com/send1

画面表示：responce=23swde7688j9jse
```

*補足

```
<script type="text/javascript">
・・・・・
function send1(){
    send_flag = true;
    xhr.open( 'POST','https://xxxx.com/send1/', false );
    xhr.setRequestHeader( 'Content-Type', 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded' );
    xhr.send('USER=u1&PWD=p1');
    xhr.abort();
}

</script>

<form method="POST">
<input name="USER" id="USER" type="hidden" value=""/>
<input name="PWD" id="PWD" type="hidden" value="" />
<input type="submit" value="送信" onclick="send1()">
</form>
```

Comment: 画面に`url:`や`response=`と表示しているのは`https://server.com/send1`でしょうか？(PHPタグが付いているのでPHPスクリプト？)

Comment: cubick様、定かではないのですが、phpスクリプトだと思われます。
urlにはhttps://server.com/send1と表示され（申し訳ございません。urlは簡略化したものです。）、画面にresponceが表示されます。（背景白）

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> 以上のフォームの送信ボタンをクリックすると以下が表示される。（responceは正しい内容）

form で　submitすると、パラメータを送信して サーバからのレスポンス待ちに状態遷移してしまい、表示やjavascriptなどが初期化されて　サーバからの結果のみが表示されます。

初期化されないようにサーバからのレスポンスを、サーバの別スクリプトへ送り返すには、submit（送信）もXMLHttpRequestなどで行う必要があります。  
(以下のサンプルは、エラー、クロスドメイン制約などは考慮していません。)

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
    var send_flag = false;

    xhr.onreadystatechange = function() {
        switch ( xhr.readyState ) {
            case 0:
                console.log( '未初期化' );
                break;
            case 1:
                console.log( '送信中' );
                break;
            case 2:
                console.log( '待ち' );
                break;
            case 3:
                console.log( '受信中:'+xhr.responseText.length+' bytes.' );
                break;
            case 4:
                if( xhr.status == 200) {
                    var data = xhr.responseText;
                    console.log( '受信完了:'+data );
                    if(send_flag){
                        var xhr2 = new XMLHttpRequest();
                        send_flag = false;
                        xhr2.open( 'POST','/send2/', false );
                        xhr2.setRequestHeader( 'Content-Type', 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded' );
                        xhr2.send('USER=u1&PWD=p1');
                        xhr2.abort();
                    }


                } else {
                    console.log( '失敗しました: '+xhr.statusText );
                }
                break;
        }
    };

function send1(){
    send_flag = true;
    xhr.open( 'POST','/send1/', false );
    xhr.setRequestHeader( 'Content-Type', 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded' );
    xhr.send('USER=u1&PWD=p1');
    xhr.abort();
}


</script>
    <input type="submit" value="送信" onclick="send1()">
```

**追記、JavaScriptで　formタグをsubmitするには**
  単純には、あらかじめsend2用の空formを作成しておき　JavaScriptでinputタグを追加してからformタグをsubmitします。

**JavaScriptからsubmitする例**

```
　<form name="send2" id="f2" method="get" action="http://yyz.jp/send2/"></form>

<script type="text/javascript">
var out1 = '<input type="text" value="a" name="USER">';
out1 += '<input type="text" value="b" name="PWD">';
document.getElementById('f2').innerHTML = out1;
document.send2.submit();
</script>
```

Comment: yyz様、ご教授、そして記述を頂きまして大変感謝いたします。本当に参考になりました。send1に情報を送信してresponse=23swde7688j9jseの値が画面に表示されれております。
その値自体である(23swde7688j9jse)をsend2に送信する必要があります。勘違いしていたら申し訳ございませんが、この値を取得し、send2に送信する記述はどこになりますでしょうか。

Comment: サンプルコード中の　xhr.onreadystatechangeの”case 4”でsend2へ送信します（送信後のステータスチェックは省いています。）

Comment: yyz様、再度恐縮でございます。上記に記述を補足致しました。xhr.open内では、ドメインの異なるサーバーへPOST送信しますのでURLを挿入しなければなりません。送信をクリックすると、元の画面に戻ってしまいます。どこに問題があるかお分かりになりませんでしょうか。

Comment: ”JavaScriptでformタグをsubmitするには”を追記しました。（同一ドメインでないと上手く送信できないような）

Comment: yyz様、ご多忙の中貴重なお時間、そしてご教授頂きまして感謝致します。本当にありがとうございます。